# how to create an dynamic sql query from url post

Tags: php, mysql

I want to build a mysql statement with the keys i get from the POST url. Is that possible?
I have a dropdownlist in my html, so I am able to select different tables with different sizes.

So insted of (firstname, lastname), maybe i could get it from the array($keys). I'm very new to all this php. and it's for a school project.

```
<?php
//array with keys
$keys = array();

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
   array_push($keys, "$key=$value");
}

//
$sql="INSERT INTO $dbTable(firstname, lastname)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]')";
?>
```

Comment: No one got educated by asking someone else to do their homework. They just got a passing grade and continued on uneducated. That said, the answer is yes! You really can do it. Now, go try! :-)

Comment: First of all this is not 'homework'. Its a freestyle assignment. This is just a small part, and its where i got stuck. And why should i not ask a question if i don't know the answer. Do you want me to ask it when i know the answer. Thank you for being useless...

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend taking a look at how to access post parameters. A great resource is http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php. Once you have the post variables take a look at how to concatenate here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php. Something to be aware of any time you are directly putting variables into SQL though is SQL injection. Take a look at the wiki for it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

Comment: +1 For php.net - Reading the manual is always a good idea when you're new.

Comment: Thank you. I think http_build_query is the sort of thing i am looking for, not completely sure. This is all still very new to me.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question http_build_query does the opposite of what you are trying to do. Check out the docs here http://us1.php.net/http_build_query. What that does is converts an object into a serialized string.